# Is electric charge dependent on mass of an object?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, charge, mass, protons

I got this question while reading about electrons and protons where electrons having less mass than protons but possess the same amount of electric charge,though negative.

Could you please elaborate the solution in the easiest way possible for I am just a student and have not read much in depth about them.

Comment: You have correctly observed that electrons and protons have the same magnitude of electric charge, but different masses. But what's the question about that?

Comment: The positron (anti-electron) has the same charge as the proton but has the mass of the electron.  So, the simple answer is: no.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you know about the standard model then you can understand that the masses of elementary particles (except neutrinos) are due to the presence of the Higgs field. Mass is the 'charge' in gravitational forces while (electric) charge is the 'charge' in electromagnetic forces. Completely independent things.

Comment: @Amanpawar The Higgs field is a model motivated by the observations. The observations are fundamental.

Comment: @JohnDoty Higgs field was a postulated hypothetical field thought to permeate all of space, to give elementary particles their mass. Later on the Higgs boson was discovered and hence that proved the existence of the Higgs field. Let me know what you wanna know exactly if anything more.

Comment: @Amanpawar Indeed. But what motivated the hypothesis? What demanded that there were such things as "elementary particles" with mass? I'm not asking you to explain it to me: I understand it, but you don't seem to.

Comment: @JohnDoty yes ofcourse it was known that electrons, and other particles exist but they could not explain their mass. And to include mass terms in the lagrangian, they needed a scalar doublet called Higgs field. Don't forget that the Higgs boson is also an elementary particle, observed later on firstly it was hypothesized. There are many examples where people first hypothesize a certain thing and later look for it. E.g., People have hypothesized dark matter particles and now looking for them.

Comment: @Amanpawar *How* was this known? This knowledge didn't come from a bunch of fancy mathematics. And how much, really, does a complicated abstract theory with a bunch of adjustable parameters help to "explain" this knowledge?

Comment: I dont know how much knowledge you have but politely speaking you lack a very profound thing in physics: Theory and observation/experiment both runs two ways: in one way theory can come first and observation/experiment can come later and on the other way observation/experiment come first and theory can come later to explain those observation/experiment. I have just told you one of the way , where theory (Higgs field, Dark matter candidates, Dark energy, sterile neutrinos etc) come first (explains everything) and people are looking to search using observation/experiment.

Answer (score 1):

This is an experimental observation. The charges and masses of the particles are what they are. There is no grand reason: we have an elaborate theory with a couple of dozen adjustable constants, and if we adjust the constants just right we mostly reproduce particle properties, including charges and masses (but then there are those pesky neutrinos ツ ).

The experimental results are fundamental. Without them, we wouldn't have the theory. There is nothing but them to compel the theory.